# Using group by and count lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

I need to obtain the following output in a List , I am using MVC4 and C#.
Basically the query I need to execute is :

```
SELECT ESTADO, COUNT(*)
FROM VISITAS
WHERE CICLOID=ID
GROUP BY ESTADO;
```

In order to achieve this I wrote the following procedure in my Repository:

```
  public List<object> PorcentajeVisitasCiclo(Guid id)
  {
      return new List<object> {_context.Visitas
          .Where(a => a.CicloId == id)
          .GroupBy(a => a.Estado)
          .Select(n => new { Text = n.Key.Descripcion , Value = n.Count() })};
  }
```

Could you point me where I am going wrong? It doesnt give any compilation error, however it doesnt return anything

Thankd in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be an option. I had same problem and returning a list of object wasnt a solution (some LINQ error i cant remember). I went for easier solution.

```
public List<DummyModel> Method(int id)
    {
        return _context.Visitas.Where(a => a.CicloId == id).GroupBy(a => a.Estado).
            Select(n => new DummyModel { Name = n.Key.Descripcion, Value = n.Count() }).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You create a new `List<object>` containing *one* element, which is your LINQ query. That's probably not what you want.

This executes your LINQ query and then converts the result to a list:

```
return _context.Visitas.Where(a => a.CicloId == id)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Estado)
    .Select(n => new { Text = n.Key.Descripcion , Value = n.Count() }).ToList();
```

This, however, yields the problem that a `List<yourAnonymousType>` is not a subtype of `List<object>`. Hence, you need to cast your anonymous type to object first:

```
return _context.Visitas.Where(a => a.CicloId == id)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Estado)
    .Select(n => new { Text = n.Key.Descripcion , Value = n.Count() })
    .Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Of course, a better solution would be to drop the anonymous type and use an explicit class `YourDataType` with `Text` and `Value` fields/properties. Then you can simply return a `List<YourDataType>`.

Comment: Thanks. However I tested it and it asks me to convert it to  return new List<object>. I did it and it still doesnt work. Maybe the problem is in the Count?

Answer (score 1):

You can change Your return type from `List<object>` to `IEnumerable`.

BTW, `List<object>` is equal to `List`.

You can call `ToList()` extension method on Your query and return List of objects. But this will force the query to execute immediately and You will not get use of `yield return` in the future. This is bad in case Your query returns a large amount of data. All data will be loaded into memory when You call `ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
return (_context.Visitas.Where(a => a.CicloId == id)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Estado)
    .Select(n => new { Text = n.Key , Value = n.Count() })).Cast<object>().ToList();
```